# Postgres Sql syntax error at end of input

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

```
create table hall_events
(
hall_id integer,
start_date date,
end_date date
);

delete from hall_events;

insert into hall_events values 
(1,'2023-01-13','2023-01-14')
,(1,'2023-01-14','2023-01-17')
,(1,'2023-01-15','2023-01-17')
,(1,'2023-01-18','2023-01-25')
,(2,'2022-12-09','2022-12-23')
,(2,'2022-12-13','2022-12-17')
,(3,'2022-12-01','2023-01-30');

select * from hall_events;
```

This is my table

**my output shoud be **

```
hall_id start_date end_date
1       2023-01-13 2023-01-17
1       2023-01-18 2023-01-25
2       2022-12-09 2022-12-17
3       2022-12-01 2023-01-30
```

**here is my query**

```
WITH cte as
(select *,row_number()over(order by hall_id,start_date) as event_id
from(
with recursive r_cte as(select *,1 as flag from cte where event_id=1
              union all
              select cte.hall_id,cte.start_date,cte.end_date,cte.event_id,
              case when cte.hall_id=r_cte.hall_id and 
              (cte.start_date between r_cte.start_date and r_cte.end_date or
              r_cte.start_date between cte.start_date and cte.end_date) 
              then 0 else 1 end +flag
              from r_cte
              inner join cte on r_cte.event_id+1=cte.event_id)
select * from cte)x)
```

Comment: There are several problems with the query and unfortunatelt, it's not clear what the intended result is. `WITH RECURSIVE` should begin the query. Neither `WITH`nor `RECURSIVE` should appear anywhere else in the query. The keyword `RECURSIVE` doesn't mark a specific CTE as recursive, it just informs the query processor that there might be one or more recursive CTEs. Why is end_date in the third line of the expected output 2022-12-17 instead of 202-12-23?

Comment: btw: The table `hall_events` is not referenced in your query, but this is where the source data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "gaps and islands" problem where overlapping dates need to be treated as an "island". This first CTE identifies the start of each "island" of continuous dates per hall_id using the LAG function. The second CTE supplies a "group number" (i.e. to identify all rows of each island) by using a running total of the start_flag column. Then it groups by hall_id and the group number to find the minimum start_date and maximum end_date for each island.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT hall_id,
           start_date,
           end_date,
           CASE
               WHEN start_date <= LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id ORDER BY start_date) THEN 0
               ELSE 1
           END AS start_flag
    FROM hall_events
),
CTE2 AS (
    SELECT hall_id,
           start_date,
           end_date,
           SUM(start_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT hall_id,
       MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
       MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM CTE2
GROUP BY hall_id, grp
ORDER BY hall_id, start_date;
```

| hall_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-17 |
| 1 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-25 |
| 2 | 2022-12-09 | 2022-12-23* |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 | 2023-01-30 |

*note the end date for id 2 is greater than shown in the wanted result, but 2022-12-23 is the maximum date for id 2 in the data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Uq6l8dR)

If you have trouble understanding how this works, just output the result of CTE2

```
hall_id start_date  end_date    grp
1   2023-01-13  2023-01-14  1
1   2023-01-14  2023-01-17  1
1   2023-01-15  2023-01-17  1
1   2023-01-18  2023-01-25  2
2   2022-12-09  2022-12-23  1
2   2022-12-13  2022-12-17  1
3   2022-12-01  2023-01-30  1
```

and here is an alternative way of writing the query without CTE's:

```
SELECT hall_id, MIN(start_date) AS start_date, MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM (
  SELECT hall_id, start_date, end_date,
         SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id ORDER BY start_date) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT hall_id, start_date, end_date,
           CASE WHEN start_date <= LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id ORDER BY start_date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
    FROM hall_events
  ) t
) t
GROUP BY hall_id, grp
ORDER BY hall_id, start_date;
```

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_R0AXK2V

Answer (score 0):

The key gotcha is IF the new start_date should be less than or equal to the previous end_date, then it should be grouped together.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        hall_id,
        start_date,
        end_date,
        start_date <= lag(end_date, 1, 'infinity') OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id ORDER BY start_date)
        OR FALSE AS step
    FROM
        hall_events AS h1
),
cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        min(start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id,
            step),
        max(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY hall_id,
            step)
    FROM cte
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    hall_id,
    min,
    max
FROM
    cte1
ORDER BY
    hall_id,
    min,
    max;
```